# Sass mixin variable inside proprieties

Tags: html, css, sass

I was using mixin proprieties in SASS an i was wondering if there were a way to use variables inside mixins.
Here's a very simply example

```
SASS
    =overflow($axe,$show)
       overflow-$axe: $show

SCSS
  @mixin overflow($axe,$show){
    overflow-$axe: $show;
}
```

Thanks to all for further answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and called interpolation:

```
@mixin overflow($axe,$show){
    overflow-#{$axe}: $show;
}

body {
    @include overflow('x', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Ahhh i missed that  --> #
Thank you very much :)